# select distinct year from created date in mysql db table using cakephp 1.3

Tags: mysql, find, cakephp-1.3, distinct

I have working sql query that returns one row for each year that there is a report. I need the syntax for cakephp 1.3 controller to achieve the same results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Year( `dated` )
FROM `reports`
ORDER BY Year( `dated` ) ASC
```

My cakephp 1.3 queries I've tried:

```
$theYear = $this->Model->Database->find('all',array('fields'=>'DISTINCT Report.dated as Year')); // this still returns all entries, not distinct
```

or

```
$theYear = $this->Model->query('SELECT DISTINCT Report.dated from Report as Year ORDER by Report.dated ASC'); // returns bool(false)
```

also tried a function in my cake model:

```
function getYears()
{
    $ret = $this->query
      (
      "SELECT DISTINCT dated FROM reports as Year ORDER BY dated ASC"
     );
    return $ret;
} // returns NULL
```

expected results are:
2011
2012
2013

Comment: $theYear = $this->Model->Database->find('all',array('fields'=>'DISTINCT Year(Report.dated)' )); // this appears to be the correct syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$theYear = $this->Model->Database->find('all',array('fields'=>'DISTINCT Year(Report.dated)' )); // this appears to be the correct syntax
```